# semantic web add property onto single class

Tags: semantic-web, owl

Is it possible in OWL to add a property onto a single class?  So far, I see properties joining a pair of classes (like defining whether or not properties are symmetric, etc.). For example, what kind of property would I use to tag whether or not an animal is a pest.  If it matters, I'm using Protégé to construct the ontology.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by symmetric classes? Properties can be symmetric, but I'm not aware of what a symmetric class is.

Comment: My bad, I meant symmetric property. I'll edit the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is whether or not a property can have same domain and range, then yes, it is possible.
If `X` is a class and `p` is a property, it is possible to have

```
p range X
p domain X
```

and an assertion would look like:

```
i type X // an instance of X
i p i    // a self assertion
```

I'm not sure how this fits your example though: how are you modeling 'being a pest'? It looks to me like you could model this as

```
i type Pest
```

e.g., as a class assertion not a property.

Comment: isPest could also be a datatype property with boolean range.  With this approach, a class could be a subclass of (isPest hasValue true).  E.g., "Gopher subClassOf (isPest hasValue true)".

Comment: Yes that's another possibility that does not involve two classes.